# Integration of dictionaries inside a python list

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have list of dictionaries as follows:

```
[
   {
      "name":"reach",
      "values":[
         {
            "value":0,
            "end_time":"2020-09-11T07:00:00+0000"
         },
         {
            "value":1,
            "end_time":"2020-09-12T07:00:00+0000"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"impressions",
      "values":[
         {
            "value":0,
            "end_time":"2020-09-11T07:00:00+0000"
         },
         {
            "value":4,
            "end_time":"2020-09-12T07:00:00+0000"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"reach",
      "values":[
         {
            "value":1,
            "end_time":"2020-09-13T07:00:00+0000"
         },
         {
            "value":2,
            "end_time":"2020-09-14T07:00:00+0000"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I want integrate values key of dictionaries that their name key is the same as below:

```
[
   {
      "name":"reach",
      "values":[
         {
            "value":0,
            "end_time":"2020-09-11T07:00:00+0000"
         },
         {
            "value":1,
            "end_time":"2020-09-12T07:00:00+0000"
         },
        {
            "value":1,
            "end_time":"2020-09-13T07:00:00+0000"
         },
         {
            "value":2,
            "end_time":"2020-09-14T07:00:00+0000"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"impressions",
      "values":[
         {
            "value":0,
            "end_time":"2020-09-11T07:00:00+0000"
         },
         {
            "value":4,
            "end_time":"2020-09-12T07:00:00+0000"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

But I have not idea for that right now. How can I do that?
I'm a beginner to Python and may not know some of the details.
P.S: I want do that for lots of data with minimal deceleration.

Comment: Are the names unique? If so, why is this a list of dictionaries and not a single dictionary with the names as keys? That would make this much easier and faster.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Yes the names are unique. Actually it is response of api request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import chain, groupby

data = sorted(d, key=lambda x: x['name'])
res = [{'name': k, 'values': list(chain.from_iterable(y['values'] for y in g))} for k, g in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x['name'])]

print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'name': 'impressions',
  'values': [{'value': 0, 'end_time': '2020-09-11T07:00:00+0000'},
   {'value': 4, 'end_time': '2020-09-12T07:00:00+0000'}]},
 {'name': 'reach',
  'values': [{'value': 0, 'end_time': '2020-09-11T07:00:00+0000'},
   {'value': 1, 'end_time': '2020-09-12T07:00:00+0000'},
   {'value': 1, 'end_time': '2020-09-13T07:00:00+0000'},
   {'value': 2, 'end_time': '2020-09-14T07:00:00+0000'}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really first post your attempt, rather than asking for someone to do that. However:

```
new_data_dict = {}
for item in data:
    if item['name'] not in new_data_dict:
        new_data_dict[item['name']] = []
    new_data_dict[item['name']] += item['values']
new_data_list = [{'name': name, 'values': values} for name, value in new_data_dict.items()]
```

Comment: You's right I tried some ways but I did not succeed and not posting my own efforts was due to lack of attention. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
d = list() # Your initial list (you don't have to copy this line but just assign your initial list to d
result_dict = dict()

for e in d:
    if result_dict.get(e['name']):
        result_dict[e['name']].extend(e['values'])
    else:
        result_dict[e['name']] = e['values']
```

Using this code, you get your result in result_dict as key value where key is the name and value is a list of the values corresponding to this name. I think this structure is easier to maintain and you should keep working on this structure after you transformed the data.